# Implementation doesn't match interface

Tags: go, interface

I have an interface:

```
type Responder interface{
    read()(interface{})
    getError()(error)
    setError(error)
    getTransactionId()(string)
}
```

And implementation:

```
type CapacityResponse struct{
    val int32
    err error
    transactionId string
}

func (r *CapacityResponse) getError() error {
    return r.err
}

func (r *CapacityResponse) setError(err error)  {
    r.err = err
}

func (r *CapacityResponse) read() int32  {
    return r.val
}

func (r *CapacityResponse) getTransactionId() string  {
    return r.transactionId
}
```

But seems `CapacityResponse` doesn't implement `Responder` interface. What is mismatched here?

Comment: Pro tip: Use gofmt for readable code.

Comment: It would also help to include the entire error message. When a type doesn't satisfy an interface, the error usually tells why.

Comment: The read method is different.

Comment: func (r *CapacityResponse) read() int32 should same interface definition: read() interface{} , interface{} but not as int32

Comment: yes read method has interface{} as return type not int32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the interface the `read` method returns an `interface{}` whereas the CapacityResponse returns an `int32`.  Go's interface matching is done strictly on the signature of the function and does not take into consideration that an `int32` does implement the `interface{}`.  You can work around this by having two methods:

```
// This does the work
func (r *CapacityResponse) readInt32() int32  {
    return r.val
}
// This implements the interface signature
func (r *CapacityResponse) read() interface{} {
    // No type assertion necessary as int32 is an interface{}
    return r.readInt32()
}
```

There was a proposal to do what you wanted to a while ago but it got closed due to it's complexity and issues with the semantics which you can read about here:

https://github.com/golang/go/issues/12754